# Is it possible to combine two Google Maps timelines?

Tags: google-account, google-maps

I was on a trip with my wife, we both have Android phones connected to Google. Her phone had data enabled so she has a very precise timeline for her trip. Mine did not have data so the information is sparse and not precise.

Is it possible to combine (or better - replace) my timeline with hers?

Comment: I don't think It is possible being specific account related . Think of privacy concerns if one could that. If your end aim is to have a precise map for future use answers here May help http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/97919

Comment: And next when you do the same trip, use Google maps and the trip should be recorded correctly in your timeline